# Ampersand notation not working in Play framework 2.0

Tags: java, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I have a simple scala.html template created in a Playframework 2.0 project. If I reference messages with @Messages("message")

```
<div id="content">
    @Messages("test")
</div>
```

the correct string is displayed. However, if I try to use the ampersand notation from the docs

```
<div id="content">
       &{'test'}
</div>
```

it does not get replaced. What's the problem? I can't find the answere anywhere.

Comment: AFAIK, this notation is only supported in Play framework 1. Not in Play framework 2. It's not documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed `Play 1` with `Play 2` docs. In Play 2 *maaaany* things changed and you just need to make sure that you are reading proper version of the doc!

`@Messages("test")` is **default** and **only** way for getting translated messages in Play 2.

Comment: Ah, yes... Thanks, the documentation does obscure the versions a bit, especially if you arrive there by googling. Will know better next time.